# Finding all matrices for which the homogeneous system has a given solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find all $3\times 3$ matrices for which the homogeneous system has a solution space as the line $x = 2t$, $y = t$, $z = 0$. (Hint: Write the row reduced augmented matrix from given 
>   information.) What is the rank in this case?

I began by writing the augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        a&b&c&0\\
        d&e&f&0\\
        g&h&i&0
      \end{array}\right]$ and then starting applying row-reduction. Then I stopped and thought to myself "What are you doing?". It seems like there are a lot of possibilities that I have to probe separately. For example if $a = 0$ and I knew not what is not equal to $0$... I don't know how to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** if a completely row-reduced matrix has this solution, then the corresponding augmented matrix must be
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&-2&0&0\\
        0&0&1&0\\
        0&0&0&0
      \end{array}\right]
$$
Now, which matrices row-reduce to the above?

Alternatively: let $R$ denote the matrix
$$
R = \pmatrix{1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
$$
what can we do to $R$ so that its null-space remains the same?

Comment: Beat me to it.  I'll delete mine... (sigh) ;)

Comment: @Bye_World there can be more than one answer, you know... I think yours is better explained, though I would disagree with you on the definition of "row-reduced".

Comment: Yeah.  I realized it wasn't actually in RREF after I wrote it, but it's still has the correct properties, so it didn't really matter. :)

Comment: I didn't understand why the row-reduced matrix is $$
R = \pmatrix{1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
$$.

Comment: Can you find the solution to the system given by the augmented matrix?

Comment: So, the answer is all matrices formed from R's multiplications by elementary matrices. Right?

Comment: Not just elementary matrices.  We can also take combinations of elementary matrices to get arbitrary multiplication from the left by a non-singular matrix.

Comment: I was trying to mean "A matrix $A$ is in the scope of 'all 3 x 3 matrices' if and only if it can be rewritten as $A = E_{k}...E_{1}R$ where $E_{i}$'s are elementary matrices.", can't we get any nonsingular matrix by multiplying elementary matrices?

Comment: Oh, yes.  That's right.  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

if $A$ is a solution,i.e. $ker(A) = span\{(2,1,0)^T\}$ so is $EA$ for any nonsingular matrix $E$ and the converse is also true. that is if $A$ and $B$ have the same null space.

the matrix $U = \pmatrix{1 & -2 & 0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$ is the unique reef of all the matrices. so $A = EU, B = FU$ where $E$ and $F$ are nonsingular matrices. what is more they are the product of elementary row matrices.

the answer to your question is all matrices $EU$ and only those matrices,where $E$ is any nonsingular matrix, has $span\{(2,1,0)^T \}$ for the null space.